# Fortunately, nowadays

Tags: word-usage

Is it too redundant to say “Fortunately, nowadays” ?  If it is, then what should I say instead ? Or should I choose just one of them? 
It is for an essay.

Comment: Depending on the formality of 'voice' your instructor is looking for, 'nowadays' could rankle them, however redundancy wouldn't be the issue.  "Nowadays" to me sounds conversational.... common enough for an a news article but less common in say, a scientific paper which are still fairly formal.  To a tiny extent,  because 'fortunately' is also somewhat conversational, two conversational words together could seem like a double dose of that. (although, I would listen to others)

Comment: @Tom22 Could you please give me an example of other words I could use so that it doesn’t sound conversational?

Comment: It would help to know your general subject. In  some cases choices could sound too formal.  Say the subject addressed students' access to research resources.  "In the the past, working students needed to find transportation to a library to research assignments in the evenings after work.  Today, students who's families can afford an internet connection can find many sources from home without a trip out of the house." "Fortunately today" isn't so bad.  Today,(or "In 2018'"?) 'fortunate students' or "students are fortunate to be able' are possibilities (meaning slightly different things)

Comment: Proof-reading isn't on-topic here, and I could be steering you wrong in details.  I just wanted to point out that the back to back informality might sound awkward where one alone might not - not a redundancy in meaning.

Comment: I ~have~ heard "Fortunately, nowadays"  though ! I am not criticizing it too firmly.

Comment: If you want to sound less "colloquial", you could just use the word "modern" or something, e.g. "Fortunately, modern automobiles get more gas mileage than older models." You could also use "current" / "currently", "contemporary"

Answer (score 2):

Why would that be redundant? "Fortunately" doesn't have anything to do with the time setting. "Nowadays" does. Together, the two words have a different meaning than apart, so they aren't at all redundant.